# How to list out previous command arguments input to minibuffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Often I need to do replacement with text. I am looking for a way to avoid repeatedly input replacement text.

For example, firstly, I replaced `a` with `b` in text;

Secondly, I replaced `c` with `d`.

Thirdly, I need to replace `a` with `b` again. However, Emacs only store last replacement as default argument.

What is the way to list previous replacement argument, i.e. `a` to `b`?

Comment: Can you clarify what command you're using?

Comment: @Dan For this specific replacement command, I use `C-M-%`. But I am also looking forward to find solution for generic commandS.

Comment: Then @legoscia's answer is correct: you can cycle through the history with the arrow keys.  (That works for a large number of commands, not just `query-replace`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The responses you give to `M-%` (and other commands that get input from the minibuffer) are kept in the history.  Hit the "Up" key to see them.

As the search texts and the replacement texts are kept in the same history, in your case above the history would be `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.  So, when prompted for the search text, you'd need to hit "Up" four times to come back to `a`.  The history would then change to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `a`, so to get back to `b` as replacement text you'd again need to hit "Up" four times.

You can use `M-p` instead of "Up" if you prefer.

Comment: It works! Compared to `Up` and `Down`, I personally prefer `M-p` and `M-n`, which doesn't require much hand movement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what the previous minibuffer values were without invoking another command you can directly inspect the minibuffer-history variable: `C-h v` `minibuffer-history`. This will list all of the values together with the description of this variable.